# Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X Unsupported architecture (arm64) with Unsupported runtime (102)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos-big-sur, node-sass

**Mac OS 11.6 on Apple M1 chip**

node version is 17.0.1

`% node -v`

`v17.0.1`

this error appears to have literally come from nowhere I can discern. ( I checked my software updates and there was no recent OS update)

developing an app locally on Rails 6.1.4.1

the Gemfile says sass-rails is 5.1.0

this error came out of literally nowhere because this app worked fine locally yesterday

```
aos.css:7 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X Unsupported architecture (arm64) with Unsupported runtime (102)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
```

already tried:

`yarn remove node-sass`

`yarn add node-sass@4.14.1`

Comment: What is your current node version? Can you details about that?

Comment: updated. Can I just implode everything and start again? This bug literally came out of absolutely nowhere and has forced me to use my backup laptop. Meanwhile, MacOS is now saying this laptop is time for an upgrade to macOS Monterey, but i really don't want to spend the next week debugging more dev issues after the upgrade. I remember when things "just worked" ... 2021 has been a major downhill ride for productivity on MacOS as a developer, it's seriously disappointing how much time takes.

Answer (score -1):

This is resolvable with

`rm -rf tmp/` on the root of the Rails app.